# How to remove orphaned features

Tags: feature

I found some orphaned features under **`_layouts/ManageFeatures.aspx?Scope=Site`** but they do not show up when I list them up with powershell (`get-spgetfeature -site url`). They are not in 14 hive and cannot be found through the **SharePoint Manager**.

What can I do to remove these features?

Comment: [Similar question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10595/what-is-causing-a-cannot-find-a-feature-error-when-uninstalling-a-solution)

Comment: stsadm -o uninstallfeature -id <GUID> -force Thanks a lot! It worked also for me

Answer (score 59):

I have had this problem, too. The reason why they don't show up in PowerShell is the missing Scope, those feature are orphaned, indeed. We cannot use `-Site` parameter. What you can is to list it in PowerShell without `-Site` parameter and filter out those without Scope:

```
Get-SPFeature | ? { $_.Scope -eq $null }
```

This will give you a complete list of orphaned features.

[image: Obviously, I had a lot of orphaned features on my Development Environment]

Now you have to find your feature and delete it. You cannot use Id for getting your feature, neither use Unistall-SPFeature cmdlet with Id:

> Uninstall-SPFeature : Cannot find a Feature object with Path or Id: a4d208a3-b4fa-4bca-bb34-be4d30156b63 in scope
>   Local farm.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Uninstall-SPFeature a4d208a3-b4fa-4bca-bb34-be4d30156b63
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...ninstallFeature:SPCmdletUninstallFeature) [Uninstall-SPF
>      eature], SPCmdletPipeBindException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletUninstallFeature

The workaround is to use the **DisplayName** to get the spfeature (actually SPFeatureDefinition) and then [delete it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfeaturedefinition.delete(v=office.15).aspx).

```
$feature = Get-SPFeature | ? { $_.DisplayName -eq "My_Orphane_Feature" }
$feature.Delete()
```

I have tested this code and it has worked for me.

You can even use this code to clean all the orphaned features:

```
Get-SPFeature | ? { !$_.Scope } | % { $_.Delete() }
```

This line of code gets all the orphaned features and removes them.

**BUT be extremely careful with this " Get-SPFeature | ? { !$*.Scope } | % { $*.Delete() }" as in some cases it removed the Farm Features in Central Administration which is a big issue only running the configuration wizard helped.**

Comment: Thanks, just had to use this myself - one dev box, multiple dev branches, not retracting a newer branch before deploying an older one = orphaned features when deploying the old one over the new :(

Comment: Thanks this worked! Used Uninstall-SPFeature and stsadm -o uninstallfeature but none worked..then finally found your script above and that worked!

Comment: What can I do if it is not in the list of features? But it shows in the log...

Comment: Thank you! Added this to my "useful scripts" onenote notebook...

Comment: BE VERY CAREFUL WITH THIS: These features may show up as orphaned on one server, but not others. Run `Get-SPFeature | ? { !$_.Scope }` on all servers in your farm before deciding they are orphaned.

Answer (score 7):

To my surprise this worked for me:

```
stsadm -o uninstallfeature -id <id-of-feature-missing> -force
```

Found in this blog post [Sharing Minds - by Anthony Butcher](http://www.sharingminds.com.au/Blog/Post/5/Forcibly-Removing-SP-Features--)

Answer (score 6):

You can try tu use

[SharePoint Manager 2010](http://spm.codeplex.com/)
or

[SharePoint Feature Administration and Clean Up Tool](http://www.featureadmin.com/)

Answer (score 3):

I used following command to remove feature from Site Collection Administration : Features interface

```
stsadm -o uninstallfeature -id <GUID> -force
```

GUID of feature (which you want to remove) can be found in View Source of page.

Comment: this is actually the same as my answer 3 months earlier :D

Answer (score 3):

You can try [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10595/what-is-causing-a-cannot-find-a-feature-error-when-uninstalling-a-solution#answers-header) and [second Reference](http://itfreesupport.com/2014/09/sharepoint-2010-2013-issue-the-solution-cannot-be-deployed-the-feature-uses-the-directory-in-the-solution-however-it-is-currently-installed-in-the-farm-to-the-directory-uninsta/), this one I have refered fist time.

For this you need the add the **Feature Id** and then **-Force** is important.
Without force it works sometimes but definitely works with **-Force**.
Hope this will be helpful.