# How can I identify missing features in a SharePoint site that has been restored from a different farm?

Tags: feature, restore

I recently inherited an application from a developer who is no longer with the company. This application restores SharePoint sites from backups and extracts metadata and files from lists in the site. The application runs on a SharePoint server and uses the Microsoft.SharePoint assemblies in C# and VB.Net.

The backups come to us from various outside companies, and some of them have custom features installed. SharePoint Health Analyzer shows a warning about "Missing server side dependencies". When I look at the report there is a lot of "[MissingFeature] Database [db name] has reference(s) to a missing feature..." etc. The previous developer was supposed to implement a check for missing features, but it is obviously not working.

How can I identify features that the restored site references, but are not installed on the farm?

Thanks!

RH

Comment: Refer to the question on Stackexchange [How to remove orphan features][1] This might help


  [1]: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16525/how-to-remove-orphaned-features

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are couple of ways.

1. Run the Test-spcontentDatabase command against the content DB to get the list
2. use this [SharePoint Feature Administration and Clean Up Tool](http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/) to identify and remove them
3. You can use the powershell to get this done. http://get-spscripts.com/2011/08/diagnose-missingwebpart-and.html